# Android Studio - Augmented Reality, Render 3D Model on Image target

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, vuforia, easyar

I am making an Augmented Reality App, and the iOS app is already made with Vuforia. Now I need to make the Android version. The only AR functionality I need an Image Marker (recognizer), and to place a 3D model on top on it.
I don't want to use ARCore (I want more available devices'), so I need to use a Framework.
I have (of course) tried Vuforia, and successfully set up the sample project. But I don't know how to import the Imager Marker functionality into my own project. The documentation for Vuforia in Android Studio is very limited. So after hours of working, I gave up...
Then I was recommended EasyAR, and I have now successfully imported the Image Marker functionality to my project, and render a colored cube on the top of my Image Marker. But I need to render my 3D model, instead of the cube and I don't know how to do that.

So have 2 questions, but one answer can make the difference.

1. How to import the Image Marker functionality from Vuforia and render your own 3D object? (Any file-type)
2. How to change the EasyAR standard rendered cube to a 3D object?

Any other possible solutions are also welcome.

Comment: I am not an Android developer but with a rough research i have found [vuforia samples](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples?d=windows-31-22-7343&retU) for Android Studio. It has a class called `ImageTargetRenderer` and `ImageTargets` classes that might help you. If you give more details about where you got stuck in image targets i can try to help

Comment: I have studied the Vuforia samples pretty hard. But I can't get a grib on which classes I need to import to my on project to get the session for ImageTargets. The sample project has all the assets, and a 'SampleApplication' folder with files like 'SampleApplicationSession' and a folder inside called 'utils'. Then there is the 'VuforiaSamples' folder, with the 'app' (ImageTargets, CloudRecognition etc.) and a folder called 'ui'. And the I have some xml-files in drawable. And ofc Vuforia.Jar. I just don't know which files I need to import to my own project, to get the Session I want.

Comment: Well from Unity point of view there should be only 1 session with correct session configuration for your case. You have to configure and initiate a Vuforia Session then you can use the classes i mentioned in the first comment. So there should not be a case where you think which session to use. You have to configure your session according to your own needs. Apparently they use a .txt file to load model and use a function called `SampleApplication3DModel`